# how to write query for add and delete operations at a time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have two tables,I have a button control,when i click on the button that record in table2 added to table1 and that record has to delete in table2.
 I wrote like

```
public ActionResult Accept( int id, string selectedVal)                         //To update Accept status
        {
            var retrieveID = (from i in dbContext.groups
                              where i.groups_name == selectedVal
                              select new { groups_id = i.Usr_contacts_groups_id }).FirstOrDefault();

          var currentId = 1;
            var deleteQuery = dbContext.requests.Where(i => i.from_usr_id == id && i.to_usr_id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            contact contactGroup = new contact();

            contactGroup.groups_id = retrieveID.groups_id;
            contactGroup.groups_usr_id = currentId;



            this.dbContext.Add(contactGroup);
            this.dbContext.Delete(deleteQuery);
            try
            {
                this.dbContext.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
            return Json(null);
        }
```

I am able to add record in the table1 and deleting multiple records in table2 with "id" value in delete query.

Comment: delete only that particular record not multiple records

Comment: What's the primary key of `table2`?

Comment: I have edited my question,My primary keys are userId ,bioId  in table2

Comment: What is your question? And is this your actual code? It won't compile.

Comment: Please show your mapping code.

Comment: You're making a mess out of this question. Now `bioid` suddenly is out? I suspect that there is a mismatch between your db PK and the PK that EF knows of. Can't tell without seeing your mapping. Stabilize your code first though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that record in table2 added to table1 and that record has to delete in table2

I will assume, in plain English:

> That record in `table2` should be added into `table1` and then deleted from `table2`

in other words, **Move record** from `table1` into `table2`, right? *(let's assume it is)*

```
public ActionResult MoveRecord(int id) {

    // get Table 2 record
    var recordA = dbContext.table2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.bioId == id);

    // if we did find a record
    if (recordA != null) {

        // let's add it into Table 1
        var recordB = new Table2();
        recordB.id = recordA.id;
        recordB.value = recordA.value;

        // add to database
        dbContext.table1.AddObject(recordB);

        // now that we have it in the database, let's delete the original on
        dbContext.table2.DeleteObject(recordA);

        // save all changes
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }


    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Never mind balexandre. The OP changes his mind every 10 min. I think the issue's got to do with PK mismatches.